# Shifting array elements using bitwise operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am new to programming.

I just want to know, is there any way to shift array elements using the bitwise operator? Maybe with overloading the bitwise operator?

If it is possible, why are we not using this method when bitwise operators are faster compared to arithmetic operators?

Example

```cpp
int array[] {1, 2, 3};
array << 1; // -> array should become 2, 3, 1
```

Comment: Bitwise operators are not faster than arithmetic operators. That might be true in assembly, but it is not true in C++, because C++ compilers will replace arithmetic operations with the equivalent bitwise operations if the bitwise operations are faster.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the main question, you should illustrate what you mean with an example.

Comment: The question is pretty vague. What particular arithmetic operator would you want to replace with a bitwise operator, and what does that have to do with array elements? A code sample would help, as a basis for the question. If your question is simply, can you use a bitwise operator on an array element, then yes. For example, `myArray[5] >>= 1` would shift the sixth element of `myArray` right by one bit. Is that all you're asking? Please clarify.

Comment: It seems like you have some misconceptions about how C++ operator and operator overloading works. Just because you overload a bitwise operator doesn't mean that the compiler will actually generate bitwise CPU instructions.

Comment: Also remember that C and C++ are two ***very*** different languages. Just the fact that you mention operator overloading means you're in the C++ realm, as C doesn't have it. Please don't tag multiple languages, even if they might seem the same. And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to know that is there any way to shift array elements using bitwise operator. Maybe with overloading the bitwise operator.

You probably mean to do something like

```
int array[] {1, 2, 3};
array << 1; // -> array should become 2, 3, 1
```

This is not possible. For operator overloading one of the operands must be of class type, but neither `array`, nor `1` are classes. You can overload this operator for containers like `std::array` or `std::vector` of course.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void operator<<(std::array<T, N> &arr, int n) {
    // shift things around, the implementation is up to you ;)
}

void foo() {
    std::array<int, 3> array {1, 2, 3};
    array << 1; // -> array becomes 2, 3, 1
}
```

> Even if it is possible why we are not using this method while bitwise operator are the faster compare to arithmetic operators?

Not sure what you mean here. Overloading a bit-shift-operator (or any operator for that matter) doesn't do any actualy bit shifting, it's just a fancy way to call some function.